# Blazor .NET 7.0 - Inject service in program.cs before builder.Build()

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, policy

I have a Blazor Server App running on .NET 7 and I'm trying to dynamically add policy in `Program.cs` from some data source (api/sql)

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("IT_Read", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        context.User.HasClaim(c =>
            c.Type == "groups" &&
            (c.Value == Group_IT_User ||
            c.Value == Group_IT_Admin)
        )
    );
});
```

So I did create my `IPolicyService` which will get policy data and now I'm struggling how to fetch these data in `Program.cs`.
I can inject service after app is build, but I guess I need to inject it before its build so I can `AddPolicy` to builder.

I found one option with code below

```cs
using (var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
    var policyService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPolicyService>();
    var dynamicPolicies = await policyService.GetDynamicPoliciesAsync();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        foreach (var item in dynamicPolicies)
        {
            options.AddPolicy(......);
        }
    };
 }
```

But I'm not sure if I can ignore warning:

> Calling BuildServiceProvider from application code results in an
> additional copy of singleton services being created.

So

1. What would be correct approach to `AddPolicy` dynamically?
2. Is it ok to BuildServiceProvider and have copy of singleton service?
3. Can I Add Policy after `var app = builder.Build();` ?